# Magento2: contact page - issue with captcha "incorrect' not showing

Tags: magento2, captcha

After enabling captcha for the contact form the captcha is not shown on the form. If submitted an "Incorrect CAPTCHA" error is displayed. Tried in production and development modes. No Javascript errors in the console.

Preconditions

Magento 2.1.6

PHP 7.0.12

MYSQLl 15.1 10.0.27-MariaDB

Varnish 4.1.3

Redis 3.2.3

Steps to reproduce

Select stores->Configuration->Customers->Customer Configuration->Captch->Forms->Contact us and save

captcha

Refresh caches

Clear varnish cache

We check links:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9635

[Magento 2 CAPTCHA not showing when enabled](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224649/magento-2-captcha-not-showing-when-enabled)

But I think that there is not completely understood how to solve this problem. Can anyone give an answer here?

Comment: Can you check PHP logo in your system? Is there any hint on that?

Comment: Solution could be read/write access (fixing permissions) to var/* and pub/*.

Comment: We have valid write permissions for the var and pub directories.

Comment: What is your Magneto version ?  is there any error or exception is there in php log/nginx/apache log file ?

Comment: Magento ver. 2.2.5. Let me check

Comment: I do not see any error or exception in log file. You can try send msg to us:  https://gerris.cz/contact