# Magento2: captcha not showing on contact page

Tags: captcha

After enabling captcha for the contact form the captcha is not shown on the form. If submitted an "Incorrect CAPTCHA" error is displayed. Tried in production and development modes. No Javascript errors in the console.

**Preconditions**

Magento 2.1.6

PHP 7.0.12

MYSQLl 15.1 10.0.27-MariaDB

Varnish 4.1.3

Redis 3.2.3

Steps to reproduce

Select stores->Configuration->Customers->Customer Configuration->Captch->Forms->Contact us and save

captcha

Refresh caches

Clear varnish cache

Comment: You have try this links :- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9635

Comment: Check these links,
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224649/magento-2-captcha-not-showing-when-enabled
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212155/captcha-form-not-visible-after-applying-theme